# Is it possible to run AFNetworking and Alamofire at the same time in the same app?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, afnetworking

I'd like to migrate from AFNetworking to Alamofire in a grown app. Since the app is quite big we think a step by step migration would contain less risk.

Nevertheless we have some concerns regarding:

- Sessions
- Security (Pinning etc.)
- Observers / Listeners
- Queues
- Caching
- ...

Does anyone has experience with mixing AFN and Alamofire in Swift apps? I am also grateful for reports of problems you faced running both frameworks in parallel.

Thanks

Comment: they both are the same. Alamofire is Swift version whereas AFNetworking is the Objective-C version. Also, Alamofire is not supported on iOS 7. so if you are using swift then you should use Alamofire.

Comment: Thanks Abid, I agree with you but the question is if there is a need for both frameworks at the same time do they work together. I search for people with experience with both frameworks and if they figured out any kind of issue as I listed in the original post.

Comment: There is no need to use both of the frameworks at the same time. you can use it but it's not good practice.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible and I've done so many times. You should try it and see what issues you run into and ask specific questions about them.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest you should stick with AFNetworking. `Having two frameworks that do the same thing isn't always desired` event in short term. AlamoFire is better if we in Swift only project. If you have 90% ObjC, it's just not ideally. And the result could be a lot of hidden bugs.